# Mosquitto broker socket error

Tags: linux, mqtt

After updating to mosquitto v1.5.5 from 1.4.x I have not been able to connect to the broker, I have tried using an esp module as well as raspberry pi and mosquitto_sub. However, when I run mosquitto_sub from the computer which is also running the broker It conects successfully. I've also tried connecting using a python script from the localhost and it works. 
I'm thinking it's something to do with the update authentication on v1.5 however my my config file which includes only one line should handle this since I've added "allow_anonymous true".

Does anyone have any ideas? All im getting on the output is: **socket error on client XXX, disconnecting** .

Also when I run the broker on the pi (v1.4) it works perfectly and my esp module can connect to it without a problem. 
Moreover, I've added a password file and tried to connect to the broker from the esp module using the unsername and password specified on the broker password file without any success.

Thank you.